# Getting Friend's Timeline Using Twitter4j API

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have started learning Twitter4j API and have got all credentials and tokens from Twitter to use it.
Now i am trying to get a timeline of my friend using a simple java program and print it on console.

```
       ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
       cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
           .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
           .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
           .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
           .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);
     try 
     {
          TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
          Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
          String[] srch = new String[] {"usernameoffriend"};
          ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(srch);
          for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println("Friend's Name " + user.getName()); // this print my friends name
                if (user.getStatus() != null) 
                {
                System.out.println("Friend timeline");
                List<Status> statusess = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
                for (Status status3 : statusess) 
                 {
                        System.out.println(status3.getText());
                 }
    }
}
```

The code is not giving errors. But instead of printing my Friend's Timeline it is printing **MY** own Timeline.
I am using **getFriendsTimeline()** . Then why it is not printing my Friend's Timeline.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getFriendsTimeline()` is deprecated on the latest build of twitter4j, use `getUserTimeLine()`;

So to get TimeLine of friend: `getUserTimeline("pseudo")`

```
 ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
           cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
               .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
               .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
               .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
               .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);
         try 
         {
              TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
              Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
              String[] srch = new String[] {"usernameoffriend"};
              ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(srch);
              for (User user : users) {
                System.out.println("Friend's Name " + user.getName()); // this print my friends name
                    if (user.getStatus() != null) 
                    {
                    System.out.println("Friend timeline");
                    List<Status> statusess = twitter.getUserTimeline(user.getName());
                    for (Status status3 : statusess) 
                     {
                            System.out.println(status3.getText());
                     }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @animuson with getUserTimeline("name") i am for some names i am getting correct data and for some name i am getting my timeline data any idea what i am doing wrong here. I am using twitter4j version 3.0.3

Comment: @animuson solved the problem by using user id instead of name.use user.getId() instead of user.getName()